# AWS- Dynamo : UpdateItem throws error on Index GSI

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to update an element like this

```
$response = $dynamo->updateItem(array(
    "TableName" => "posts",
    "IndexName" => "college_id-post_id-index",
    "Key" => array(
        "college_id" => array('S' => $collegeId),
        "post_id" => array('S' => $postId )
    ),
    "ExpressionAttributeValues" =>  array (
        ":reply" => $reply
    ),
    #"UpdateExpression" => "set reply = if_not_exists(reply , :reply)",
    "UpdateExpression" => "set reply = :reply",
    "ReturnValues" => 'ALL_NEW'
));


college_id-post_id-index is Global Secondary Index having hash key `college_id` and range key `post_id` .
```

When I am performing update then I am getting error `The provided key element does not match the schema`

Can any one help me what could be the problem ?

Comment: Can you paste the output of DescribeTable call? Do you have a schema for the base table with college_id and post_id as the hash and range keys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned, could you please share the schema of your base table?

It sounds like you are trying to update the GSI of the table directly - which is not possible in DynamoDB. When you create a GSI on a DynamoDB table, DynamoDB keeps track of the GSI and ensures it is automatically updated as the base table items are updated.

In this case, assume you have a base table (I don't know the schema but I'll assume you have post_id as hash key and college_id as range key). You could try the following slightly modified code:

```
$response = $dynamo->updateItem(array(
"TableName" => "posts",
"Key" => array(
    "post_id" => array('S' => $postId ),
    "college_id" => array('S' => $collegeId)
),
"ExpressionAttributeValues" =>  array (
    ":reply" => $reply
),
"UpdateExpression" => "set reply = :reply",
"ReturnValues" => 'ALL_NEW'
));
```

The above request will update the corresponding item in the base table, but also the GSI will be updated as well to reflect the new values.

You can read more about data synchronization between the base table and GSI [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GSI.html#GSI.Writes).